# Weird display issue with WinForms images

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a small program created in C# using WinForms and it always displayed well on test devices except for my Lenovo ThinkPad touchscreen laptop. Here are two screenshots to show the display issue.

The top one is the correct view taken on the same laptop but through an RDP connection to another machine.

The bottom one shows the issue.

Any ideas?

[image: Normal display (also on from Laptop but connected to another machine w/ RDP)]

[image: Weird display issue!]

Comment: I also see the same effect when designing in VS 2013 on the laptop.

Comment: So, shot in the dark here, but what are the DPI settings of the two machines?  The top one looks blurry.

Comment: AHHA! I think you got it on the first try. I changed the DPI setting in Windows, rebooted and it works fine. Now I'm just curious if there's a best practice to follow when designing that would create a DPI safe UI.

Comment: You don't use absolute sizes/positions.  I'll find an existing topic

Comment: You can use WPF or Set [AutoScaleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.autoscalemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to None to prevent scaling or any other if you prefer to scale.